Can you do better than partial fraction decomposition?
Consider the function $f_3(x)=\frac1{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$. We can think of computing some sort of partial fraction decomposition for $f_3(x)$. For example,
$$f_3(x)=\frac{1/6}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{1/2}{(1-x^2)(1-x)}+\frac{1/3}{1-x^3}.$$
There is a structure in the choice of denominators on the right-hand side, which will now be formalized in my question. This relies on integer partitions.

QUESTION. If $\lambda=(1^{m_1},2^{m_2},\dots,n^{m_n})$ is a partition of $n$ then let $z_{\lambda}:=1^{m_1}2^{m_2}\cdots n^{m_n}m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!$. Is there a conceptual or combinatorial proof for this identity?
$$\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{1-q^k}=\sum_{\lambda\,\vdash n} 
\frac1{z_{\lambda}}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{1-q^k}\right)^{m_k}.$$

In the above example, for $f_3(x)$, the corresponding partitions are associated with $n=3$. Namely, $\lambda=(1^3), (2,1), (3)$ leading up to the denominators $(1-x)^3, (1-x^2)(1-x), (1-x^3)$, respectively.

By the way, for any integer $n,\ 1-x^n$ can be factorised. Either you didn't think of this when you wrote the question, or it is irrelevant to the question.

It is not immediately clear to me how your example fits into the general question. How do the three terms of $f_3$ correspond to partitions of $n=3$?

@AdamRubinson: we don't bother to factorize like that. That is the point.

@Lieven: I'll elaborate that now.

@AdamRubinson: thank you for the pointers.

Do you have a proof already that's just not "conceptual or combinatorial"? Or is this a conjecture?

And, if it is a conjecture, have you verified it for a bunch of values of $n$?

I can prove this using partial fractions by using roots of unity. Tedious.

Andrews and Eriksson, Integer Partitions, give $$f_3(x)={1/6\over(1-x)^3}+{1/4\over(1-x)^2}+{1/4\over1-x^2}+{1/3\over1-x^3}$$ and $$f_4(x)={1/24\over(1-x)^4}+{1/8\over(1-x)^3}+{(5/12)^2\over(1-x)^2}+{1/8\over(1-x^2)^2}+{1/16\over1-x^2}+{(2+x)/9\over1-x^3}+{1/4\over1-x^4}$$ They leave finding $f_5$ as an exercise.

But, notice that in our problem the numerators are constants. What you depicted here for $f_4(x)$ is the classical partial fractions.

The classical partial fraction decomposition would have terms with denominators $1+x$, $1-x$, $1+x+x^2$, and $1+x^2$, which the Andrews-Eriksson decomposition doesn't have, so it's not quite classical. I take your point about the numerator $(2+x)/9$ and I'm not sure why they didn't try to find a way around that.

I can give a combinatorial proof of this equation, in terms of generating functions in the variable $q$.
Let $P_n(s)$ denote the number of partitions of $s$ with at most $n$ parts. It is a standard result that
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{1-q^k}=\sum_{s=0}^\infty P_n(s)q^s\tag1
$$
It is also well known that $n!/z_\lambda$ is the number of permutations $\pi\in S_n$ with cycle type $\lambda$. This allows you to rewrite the RHS of your equation like this:
$$
\sum_{\lambda\,\vdash n} 
\frac1{z_{\lambda}}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{1-q^k}\right)^{m_k}=
\frac1{n!}\sum_{\pi \in S_n} 
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{1-q^k}\right)^{\text{# $k$-cycles in $\pi$}}\tag2
$$
Now, extracting the coefficient of $q^s$ of both sides of the equation you want to prove, and applying $(1)$ and $(2)$, an equivalent goal is
$$
P_n(s)=\frac1{n!}\sum_{\pi\in S_n} \,[q^s]
\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{1-q^k}\right)^{\text{# $k$-cycles in $\pi$}}\tag3
$$
The LHS of $(3)$ is simple, but what to make of the RHS? The fact that we have a sum of $n!$ numbers multiplied by $\frac1{n!}$ made me think of the lemma-that-is-not-Burnside's, and led me to try to interpret the RHS as the number of orbits of an action of $S_n$ on some set. This led me to the following combinatorial interpretation of $(3)$.

Let $s$ be a positive integer, and let $C_n(s)$ be the set of weak compositions of $s$ with $n$ parts; that is, $C_n(s)$ consists of vectors of length $n$, with nonnegative integer components, whose sum is $s$. If you define an equivalence relation on $C_n(s)$, where two vectors are equivalent when you can permute the entries of one to obtain the other, then the number of equivalence classes is equal to $P_n(s)$.

The above quoted statement is delightfully obvious! It is not quite so obvious how it relates to $(3)$.
To explain why the RHS of $(3)$ is related to this combinatorial interpretation, let us count the number of equivalence classes in $C_n(s)$, up to permutation, using Burnside's lemma. We must compute the average number of fixed points over all permutations in $S_n$. Given $\pi \in S_n$, a fixed point of $\pi$ must be a vector such that any $k$ coordinates which are in  a $k$-cycle are equal to each other. I claim that the number of ways to choose a weak composition which is fixed by $\pi$ is
$$
[q^s] \prod_{k=1}^n \left(\frac1{1-q^k}\right)^{\text{# $k$ cycles in $\pi$}}.
$$
To see this, imagine expanding out this product of infinite series, and computing the contribution to the $q^s$ term. For each cycle of $\pi$, you need to choose a summand from $(1-q^k)^{-1}=1+q^k+q^{2k}+\dots$, so you choose some multiple $mk$ of $k$ to contribute to the exponent of $q$. This just like choosing a fixed point of $\pi$; if you choose to place an $m$ in some coordinate of the composition which is in a $k$-cycle, then you must place an $m$ in all coordinates, which contributes of $mk$ to the sum.

In order to show the validity of
\begin{align*}
f_n(q):=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac1{1-q^k}=\sum_{\lambda\,\vdash n} 
\frac1{z_{\lambda}}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{1-q^k}\right)^{m_k}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
\lambda&=(1^{m_1},2^{m_2},\dots,n^{m_n})\\
z_{\lambda}&=1^{m_1}2^{m_2}\cdots n^{m_n}m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!
\end{align*}

we consider the formal power series
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(t):=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(q)t^n}
\end{align*}
and show that (1) follows from the identity
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(t)=\exp\left(\log\left(F(t)\right)\right)}
\end{align*}

Recall that we can expand $f_n, n\geq 1$ as a series whose coefficients are the number of integer partitions $P_n(s)$ of $s$ with at most $n$ parts:
\begin{align*}
f_n(q)=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-q^k}=1+\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}P_n(s)q^s\qquad n\geq 1\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Introducing the generating function $F$ we can write (2) as coefficients of $F$ and get
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(t)=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(q)t^n=\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^kt}}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Note that we can write $F$ also as infinite product. Here the product starts with index $k=0$ since we not only want the number with $n$ parts but with at most $n$ parts of an integer partition at $[t^n]F(t)$.
We obtain from (3)
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{\log\left(F(t)\right)}}&=-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\log(1-q^kt)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^m}{m}\,q^{km}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^m}{m}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(q^m\right)^k\\
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^m}{m!}\frac{(m-1)!}{1-q^m}}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
We can now apply exponentiation to (4) and work with complete exponential Bell polynomials. Using the notation from Comtet's Advanced Combinatorics and denoting a complete Bell polynomial with $Y_n=Y_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ we get

\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(t)}&=\exp\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{t^m}{m!}\,\frac{(m-1)!}{1-q^m}\right)\\
&\color{blue}{=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n\left(\frac{0!}{1-q},\frac{1!}{1-q^2},\cdots,\frac{(n-1)!}{1-q^n}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!}}\tag{5}
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
Y_n&\left(\frac{0!}{1-q},\frac{1!}{1-q^2},\cdots,\frac{(n-1)!}{1-q^n}\right)\\
&\qquad=\sum_{\lambda\,\vdash n} \frac{n!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!\left(1!\right)^{m_1}\left(2!\right)^{m_2}
\cdots \left(n!\right)^{m_n}}\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot\left(\frac{0!}{1-q}\right)^{m_1}\left(\frac{1!}{1-q^2}\right)^{m_2}
\cdots\left(\frac{(n-1)!}{1-q^n}\right)^{m_n}\\
&\qquad=\sum_{\lambda\,\vdash n} \frac{n!}{m_1!m_2!\cdots m_n!\,1^{m_1}2^{m_2}
\cdots n^{m_n}}\\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot\left(\frac{1}{1-q}\right)^{m_1}\left(\frac{1}{1-q^2}\right)^{m_2}
\cdots\left(\frac{1}{1-q^n}\right)^{m_n}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

Combining (3), (5) and (6) we finally conclude
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{F(t)}&\color{blue}{=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1-q^k}\right)t^n}\\
&\color{blue}{=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{\lambda\,\vdash n} 
\frac1{z_{\lambda}}\prod_{k=1}^n\left(\frac1{1-q^k}\right)^{m_k}\right)t^n}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.

The partition sum is the cycle index $Z(S_n)$ of the
symmetric  group   $S_n$  evaluated  at   $a_\ell  =
\frac{1}{1-q^\ell}$  But  this  cycle index  is  the
unlabeled              multiset             operator
$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod} \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm
#1{\small #2}}} \textsc{MSET}_{=n}$  on $n$ slots by
PET! (Consult Analytic Combinatorics or Graphical
Enumeration.)   Here  we   have  a   repertoire  of
$1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots$       going      into       the
operator. Counting these multisets we get the OGF by
total weight of the multiset
$$[u^n] \prod_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-uq^k}.$$
Here  we are  counting partitions  consisting of  at
most  $n$ elements  counted with  multiplicity where
the elements  may be  any size corresponding  to the
repertoire which  consists of  one element  of every
size. On the other hand the term
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1-q^k}$$
counts partitions  with any  number of  elements but
element size at most $n$, also by total weight. This
proves it as we now have a bijection between the two
types of partitions, they are conjugates obtained by
flipping  the Ferrers  diagram about  the descending
diagonal and we may conclude.
Remark. If  the reader  wishes to see  the cycle
index being evaluated, it goes like this: the OGF is
$$Z(S_n) = [u^n] \exp
\left(\sum_{\ell \ge 1}
a_\ell \frac{u^\ell}{\ell}\right).$$
With  $a_\ell =  \frac{1}{1-q^\ell}$  and doing  the
substitution,
$$[u^n] \exp
\left(\sum_{\ell \ge 1} \sum_{k\ge 0} q^{k\ell}
\frac{u^\ell}{\ell}\right)
= [u^n] \exp
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \sum_{\ell \ge 1} q^{k\ell}
\frac{u^\ell}{\ell}\right)
\\ = [u^n] \exp
\left(\sum_{k\ge 0} \log\frac{1}{1-uq^k}\right)
= [u^n] \prod_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-uq^k}.$$
